# Google Forms - Add custom button "more info" in items using Google Apps Script

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-forms, programmatically-created

I am trying to add a custom button in a "Google Forms" form. 
I have widely looked in AddOns and Google Apps Script documentation but with no luck.

I would like to have a button (let's say the "i" of information) to click in case of need of more info about the question.
I don't want to expose always the long description for all the questions.

My idea was, at the event of click on the button (the info image), set the description.

Any other ideas?

[Example of image with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIRZw.png) 
[image]

Comment: Could you do it manually?

Comment: I would like to know how to do this, too!

Answer (score 2):

Create the instruction for Question 1 in a Google Doc. Write whatever you want in the DOC. Share it publicly with view rights.

Copy the url of the doc

Paste the url in bit.ly to shorten the url. Copy the url.

Edit your form

In the Question 1, in the "Description" field write

"Please click bit.ly/xxxx for instructions"

Now the user can click the above link to read the instructions in another tab.

I use it all the time.

Comment: That's.a workaround, not a solution. But it is a very good one indeed, so thank you for sharing.

Comment: @NonnoTeo I don't think what you want to do is possible at all, so a workaround is the best you can get.